# Remove everything but certain link from element using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace

I'm creating a simple website that collates all of my tweets into a "wall" using a WP plugin. The problem is though that the entire body of the tweet (Links, text, hashtags, etc.) is pulled into `the_content` whereas I only want to display the a particular chunk of content.

Is there a way that I can completely remove everything else from an element using PHP?

This is my example markup;

```
<div class="element">

    <div class="overlay">

        <p><a href="#">@username</a> This is some plain text. http://www.t.co/xxxxxxx <a href="#">#twitterhashtag</a></p>

    </div>

</div>
```

I want to remove everything apart from the `<a href="#">@username</a>`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
   <?php  $content = get_the_content();              
          $pieces = explode("</a>", $content);

      <div class="element">

          <div class="overlay">

                 <p>echo $pieces[0]."</a>";</p>

          </div>

     </div>
```